# Nested Array with json in AngularJS

Tags: php, arrays, json, angularjs

I am using angularJS for my application it have bit completion in foreach loop. I created a JSON for following array.

```
Array
(
     [0] => Array
     (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [semester_id] => 1
                [dealer_id] => 120
     )
     [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [semester_id] => 1
                [dealer_id] => 120
     )
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [semester_id] => 2
                [dealer_id] => 255
    )
)
```

I want to generate this array json as like

```
<div id="1">
  <div>
    <span>id = 2,semeter id = 1, dealerid =120</span>
    <span>id = 2,semeter id = 1, dealerid =120</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="2">
  <div>
    <span>id = 2,semeter id = 1, dealerid =255</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone please help on this

I tried this
Actually i am using Codeigniter framework with this

app.js

```
app.controller('dashboard', function($scope, $http) {
  dashboard_home(); // Load all available tasks 
    function dashboard_home(){  
      $http.post(base_url+"admin/dashboard").success(function(data){
        $scope.dashboard = data[0];
    });
  };
});
```

I am returning json data from codeigniter controller to view. I used ng-repeat but i am result like

```
<div>
    <span>id = 2,semeter id = 1, dealerid =120</span>
    <span>id = 2,semeter id = 1, dealerid =120</span>
</div>
```

two times i am getting this only. I am not getting this div

```
<div>
    <span>id = 2,semeter id = 1, dealerid =255</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek i have edited my question with my tried code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Is your issue getting the data?

```
$scope.dashboard = data.data; // maybe data.data[0] as per your code.
```

might be the correct format but you can always put a break point in your JavaScript code and watch how deep your real data goes in the response.

This looks fairly straight forward to me. Here is the HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="val in array" id="{{$index+1}}">
    <div>
        <span ng-repeat="val2 in val" >
            id = {{val2.id}},semeter id = {{val2.semester_id}},
             dealerid ={{val2.dealer_id}}
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am assuming the correct structure is this

```
Array
(
     [0] => Array
     (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [semester_id] => 1
                [dealer_id] => 120
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [semester_id] => 1
                [dealer_id] => 120
             )
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [semester_id] => 2
                [dealer_id] => 255
            )
     )
)
```